# jgroups - Failure Detection when group coordinator dies

Tags: jgroups

JGroups documentation (http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/index.html) states that when FD discovery protocol is being used, the current group coordinator is responsible of updating the cluster's view when a node of a cluster dies but it is not clear from the documentation that what is being done when the group coordinator itself dies.
For example, we have a cluster {A,B,C,D} and the node A is the coordinator here. 
Now if a new member 'E' wants to join then the coordinator start the JOIN protocol and allow E to join the cluster and if a member, say 'C', crashes then the neighbors of 'C' will broadcast a suspect message and the GMS protocol of the coordinator will exclude 'C' and broadcast the new View to the members of the cluster. This is understandable. But in case of death of the group coordinator itself then (by some logic) next member in that view takes over as coordinator.

- My question is how the next member will come to know about the new
  View?
- Is it the channel becoming the coordinator for the time being
  and install the new View to the members and each member check whether
  it is the new coordinator or not by checking the first/oldest member
  in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're looking at outdated documentation; the new one is at http://www.jgroups.org/manual/index.html.

When a coordinator dies, the second in-line will take over and become the new coordinator. So if B gets a `SUSPECT(A)` message, it knows that it needs to take over as the coord (`A`) crashed.

Note that `FD_ALL` or `FD_ALL2` are preferred over `FD` if you use `UDP` as transport.

Comment: Thanks @Bela. Sorry for looking at outdated documentation. But I still have few doubts. 
"if B gets a SUSPECT(A) message, it knows that it needs to take over as the coord (A) crashed." - that means B becomes coordinator and then B will use VERIFY_SUSPECT and eventually exclude A from the cluster and publish the new view {B,C,D} to the members. Is it so? But in that case, if it is found that after using VERIFY_SUSPECT,  A is alive then what will happen to the coordinatorship?

Comment: May I also ask a question related to this. What if B also crashes? If the member list goes like A, B, C, D... and both current coordinator and a few next candidates crash simultaneously, how does the system behave? Thanks in advance,

Comment: The next in line will take over: if both A and B crash, C will be the new coordinator.